# Cannot create pointers of an abstract class in function main()

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract

```
  #include<iostream.h>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include<string.h>
  class flight
  {
private :
int flightno;
char source[30],destination[30];
protected :
double fare;
public :
flight()
{
    flightno=0;
    source[0]='\0';
    destination[0]='\0';
    fare=0.0 ;
}
flight(int f,char s[],char d[],double fr)
{
    flightno=f;
    strcpy(source,s);
    strcpy(destination,d);
    fare=fr;
}
flight(flight &f)
{
    flightno=f.flightno;
    strcpy(source,f.source);
    strcpy(destination,f.destination);
    fare=f.fare;
}
virtual void accept()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter Fligt no :";
    cin>>flightno;
    cout<<"\nEnter source :";
    cin.getline(source,30);
    cout<<"\nEnter destination :";
    cin.getline(destination,30);
    cout<<"\nEnter fare :";
    cin>>fare;
}
virtual void display()
{
    cout<<"\nFlight number :"<<flightno;
    cout<<"\nsource        :"<<source;
    cout<<"\nDestination   :"<<destination;
    cout<<"\nflight fare   :"<<fare;
  }
   virtual double computefare()=0;
 };
 class domestic : public flight
 {
private :
int noc,noa;
double totalfare,discount;
public :
domestic()
{
    noc=0;
    noa=0;
    totalfare=0.0;
    discount=0.0;
}
domestic(int f,char s[],char d[],double fr,int nc,int na):flight(f,s,d,fr)
{
    noc=nc;
    noa=na;
    totalfare=0.0;
    discount=0.0;
}
domestic(domestic &d):flight(d)
{
    noc=d.noc;
    noa=d.noa;
    totalfare=d.totalfare;
    discount=d.discount;
}
void accept()
{
    flight::accept();
    cout<<"\nEnter no. of adults :";
    cin>>noa;
    cout<<"\nEnter no. of children :";
    cin>>noc;
}
void display()
{
    flight::display();
    cout<<"\n no. of adults :"<<noa;
    cout<<"\n no. of children :"<<noc;
    cout<<"\n total fare :"<<totalfare;
    cout<<"\n discount :"<<discount;
    if(discount!=0)
    cout<<"After disc: "<<(totalfare-discount);
}
double computefare()
{
    totalfare=noc*flight::fare*0.5+noa*flight::fare;
    if(totalfare>40000)
        discount=0.02*totalfare;
    return totalfare-discount;
}
 };
 class internatinal : public flight
 {
private :
int nop;
double totalfare,tax;
public :
internatinal()
{
    nop=0;
    totalfare=0.0;
    tax=0.0;
}
internatinal(int f,char s[],char d[],double fr,int np):flight(f,s,d,fr)
{
    nop=np;
    totalfare=0.0;
    tax=0.0;
}
internatinal(internatinal &i):flight(i)
{
    nop=i.nop;
    totalfare=i.totalfare;
    tax=i.tax;
}
void accept()
{
    flight::accept();
    cout<<"\nEnter no. of passenger :";
    cin>>nop;
}
void display()
{
    flight::display();
    cout<<"\n no. of passenger :"<<nop;
    cout<<"\n total fare :"<<totalfare;
    cout<<"\n tax :"<<tax;
    cout<<"After tax: "<<(totalfare+tax);
}
double computefare()
{
    totalfare=nop*flight::fare;
    tax=0.30*totalfare;
    return totalfare+tax;
}
 };
 int main()
 {
int i,n,ch;
double total=0;
cout<<"\n Enter no of transaction :" ;
cin>>n;
flight *f=new flight[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<"\n Enter 1 : domestic \n 2. internatinal :";
    cin>>ch;
    f[i]=ch==1?new domestic():new internatinal();
    f[i]->accept();
    total+=f[i]->computefare();
}
cout<<"\n totaL fare :"<<total;
getch();
return 0;
 }
```

I am using turdo C++ complier . My code is not able to compile the error lies in the main() in "flight *f=new flight[n];" line (error is :1.)Cannot create instance of abstract
class 'flight' in function main() 
2.) Class 'flight' is abstract because of 'flight::computefare() = 0' in function main() ).
As far as i can remember we cannot create objects of an abstract class but we can create pointers of it. And here i am creating pointers only but still m getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a pointer-to-flight, but you're also trying to create `n` flight objects: the array you're creating is an array-of-flight, not an array-of-pointer-to-flight.

So this cannot work.

You could use for instance a `std::vector<flight*>` (possibly using a smart pointer inside the container too). (Or an array of pointer-to-flight.)

For your assignment, don't try and scrunch it all up in a single line, it buys you nothing. Write it more clearly and it will work:

```
if (ch == 1)
    f[i] = new domestic();
else
    f[i] = new internatinal();
```

(The other option is to use a cast, but that will make that line even less readable.)

Comment: okk i have changed it to flight *p[50] that error is solve . but nw the error lies in "f[i]=ch==1?new domestic():new internatinal();" lines error is two operands must evaluate to the same type in main()"

Comment: @rick: Conditional operator requires both second and third operand to be of same type, hence the error. You need to use casts (static_cast<Flight*>) to resolve this error.

Comment: @rick: updated my answer, sorry hadn't seen that problem. (Also, if you can, get a more recent compiler; MinGW is a pretty good port of GCC on Windows, TurboC++ is out of date with respect to the current C++ standard.)

Comment: @mat my knowledge in pointers is very limited can you please give me the source from where i can get a full concept of pointers that includes everything ??

Comment: Just search for "c pointers" and you'll get lots of different tutorials/documents that attempt to describe them in different ways. Once you "get" how they work, it'll all make sense, but there is no one reference for this - different people need different presentations to really "get it". Read as much as you can, and experiment, and you'll get it in the end (it's not that hard, really, just a bit tricky). No single reference "includes everything" for C (and even less for C++).